# page loading very slow after new Chrome 60 update

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have noticed my web application is loading extremely slow after the latest Chrome 60 update. It is taking 40 seconds to load 286 files from localhost and a lot of the requests are stalling for ~1second. This was all loading very fast prior to the latest update so I suspect the new update has something to do with it. Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would try to verify it's a bug by finding the revision range where the behavior changes: [bisect-builds.py](https://www.chromium.org/developers/bisect-builds-py).

Comment: Do you have a URL where we can repro?

Comment: Can you try using unstable channel (v62) ? I encounter a similar bug on our application, it does not load anymore on versions 60 and 61, yet works fine using 62.

Comment: That worked for me too, ssssteffff. I installed Chrome 62 and my app is now lightening fast again.

Comment: I have lags while opening/switching/closing tabs on 61 but not on 62.

Comment: We should vote to close this question now, since it's no longer reproducible.